# choosing which pages to print in an Access report

Tags: ms-access, printing

I need to print without any option,  choose the last two pages of a report and print it. I am not strong at Access development so I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to consider [`PrintOut`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa220516%28office.11%29.aspx):

```
LastPage = Screen.ActiveReport.Pages
DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, LastPage-1, LastPage
```